# Usable IDE for Android?

Tags: php, javascript, android, ide

I'm trying to wrap my head around this whole new mobile paradigm. So I've decided to order a cheap Chinese Android based netbook, and go full immersion into Android as a full time environment for web development. Only one snag. At least from what I can tell, there don't seem to be any mature tools for web development on the platform.

First thing I did was search the Android market. Couldn't seem to find any good native apps for the purpose. Next, I did a multi day survey of the state of web based IDE's. There were a few that had a reasonable level functionality, but those were all pay services. The other thing I'm concerned about is privacy. Most of the free services (the three that I looked at) post your home directory for the world to see.

The ideal solution for a web based IDE would be something I could host myself, I think; but so far I haven't found a host yourself web IDE that has the features I want.

Or am I approaching this whole thing incorrectly?
Any and all insight would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by web-based IDE?
You can develop web application with Eclipse..

Comment: Or, even better, IntelliJ by Jet Brains.

Comment: Are u looking for a web based IDE? Try ShiftEdit

Comment: "So I've decided to order a cheap Chinese Android based netbook, and go full immersion into Android as a full time environment for web development" -- that would be akin to deciding to do server-side Web development and electing to "go full immersion" by removing the monitor from your desktop and trying to develop without one.

Answer (score 2):

- Get one of these terminal apps for Android:
  http://www.appbrain.com/app/better-terminal-emulator-pro/com.magicandroidapps.bettertermpro
  http://www.appbrain.com/app/android-terminal-emulator/jackpal.androidterm
- Set up a remote SSH server with VIM configured to how you like it.
- Log into your server using the terminal app and use VIM to writing (or compiling) anything you want to develop
- Install a web server on the ssh box to then test your website remotely from your android browser!
- eat cake

Comment: Very nice. Thank you for this.

Comment: As hackish as it sounds, it's actually the best solution for development in event that you're away from your work environment. Even more so if you normally use VIM for day to day editing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think anyone suggested Android was a good platform to develop **ON**.

It is definitely an interesting platform to develop **FOR**, but that's a totally different thing.

Writing any long text is very difficult on any touchscreen device.
Thankfully tools like [Swiftkey](http://www.swiftkey.net/) come to help us write decent emails.

But writing complex syntax with text prediction is going to be a nightmare.

Granted an android equipped netbook would have a keyboard,
but there isnt a market for people who seriously want to develop on Android as an OS.

The only decent suggestion would be a web IDE,
and of those I have only used [Cloud9](http://c9.io/)

Comment: I'm starting to see that. Thing is the philosophical shift in all this. I'm trying not to be xenophobic about the coming total and complete change of platform. If the model that everyone is selling with Android is that you're going to be able to replace your PC with one of these devices, then you should be able to do some pretty comprehensive computing with it. Unless the cloud just isn't viable enough yet, which is possible. But I don't see any reason there couldn't be anything like Netbeans or Eclipse for web or Android. Honestly I'm kind of shocked it doesn't already exist.

Comment: Sorry for voting you down, but please consider not the current, but future perspective. Bigger and larger devices are expected to run Android. PC/workstation will remain for heavy-end devs to work on at home, but how to replace a laptop?! I'd be delighted to be able to develop on the go, and many devs are required to do so. Unless Android becomes a real, generic IDE available (like Eclipse), most will stick with a windows/mac laptop or windows tablet for this very reason...

Comment: @sibidiba, I stand by the fact that there is still no usable IDE for android.

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, the platform was not intended for developers and has no tools for development. Not that it would not be possible or feasible, but note that most Android devices are touch-based and have no keyboard. It will probably never replace Linux (or Windows) on the workstation.

Comment: Maybe. But if a large enough segment of the installed base moves to Android as the trade press would seem to have you believe, then it makes sense to know the ins and outs of it, the limitations, the strengths the weaknesses. That's why I'm thinking it makes sense to do an all Android all the time experiment, and see if it's actually possible to give up my Hackintosh for one of these tiny not especially powerful web browsing machines.