# how to develop an asp.net website on an android device

Tags: android, asp.net, ide

I have been searching the web for days to find a solution that will work. Here is my scenario. I am a asp.net programmer. Due to my work hours and me taking the bus, I get very little time to sit at the computer and work on developing my websites. I do however always have my android tablet with me. I was originally going to just remote to my computer at home, but it would wipe out my data in one sitting. I am looking for a way to develop on the go with my tablet via an app or web based ide. Any suggestions???

Comment: Are you looking for an ASP IDE application under Android?

Comment: pretty much...either an app for the android system itself or a website that is the asp.net IDE

Comment: Ok, so it is more a question for Google Play than Stack Overflow. This site is only related to programming issues.

Answer (score 0):

**there is no way** to your scenario; but you have two choose:

1. buy a surface pro tablet and run visual studio and SQL and ... on it.
   [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28045526/does-surface-pro-3-run-visual-studio-sql-server-xampp-and-other-development)
2. change your technology to PHP and develop your project on android.
   [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047648/usable-ide-for-android)  but again, not easy as surface still.

Comment: It's six years now... Do we have a solution now?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit any aspx single pages already built in IIS from any server. You can update it using any ftp client. Sure, you will have no code behind or antoeventwireup but it will work.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Could9](https://c9.io/). It's a full development environment, in the cloud.

Comment: From what I have read, this is a Linux based IDE...it doesn't allow for asp.net.