# Does Surface Pro 3 run Visual studio , sql server , xampp and other development apps?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, xampp, surface

I want to know if **Surface Pro 3 i7 - i5** could run any of the following applications

such as :

> - visual studio
> - SQL server management-studio
> - xampp
> - Dreamweaver

and so on ..

Comment: Surface Pro 3 with the i5 or i7 processor runs Windows 8.1 and can run these applications, just like a regular laptop or desktop.  I have one and run SQL Server and Visual Studio.  The only issue I've run into is that the optional keypad doesn't work when Hyper-V is enabled (needed by Visual studio for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surface Pro 3 with the i5 or i7 processor runs Windows 8.1 and can run these applications, just like a regular laptop or desktop.  This should not be confused with the older Surface RT.  I run SQL Server and Visual Studio on my Surface Pro 3 but can't speak from first-hand experience about xampp and Dreamweaver.  I would expect those applications to run too.

The only issue I've run into is that the optional keypad stopped working after Hyper-V was enabled (needed by Visual studio for mobile device emulation).  I simply disabled Hyper-V as a workaround since I don't do mobile development on the device nor have a need for virtualization.  I suspect a firmware bug.  This may have been fixed in the January 2015 firmware release (which Microsoft pushes via Windows update) because I just re-enabled Hyper-V and have not yet had the problem.

Comment: i hope that sony tablets comes with windows in next :'(((((